# Give copyright in Ruby on Rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, copyright-display

I want provide to copyright notice at start of files in my Ruby on Rails project. **Can I give copyright notice in all Ruby on Rails files including auto generated files like application.rb, routes.rb. ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to review the MIT-license for that: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

but if my understanding is correct, yes you can put a copyright notice on your files.

Comment: No I just wanna know that it is valid or not? can I give copyright notice in auto generated files? is it valid?

Comment: oh you mean like own the code etc? i'm not sure about that...you prolly have to read through the whole creative commons etc

Comment: Now you understand it right. Where did I find the creative commons?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this in some ruby files available online such ashttps://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/app/models/account_deletion.rb

I needed to do the same, but I needed a tool to automate adding it to all .rb files.

I have written the following script for this reason

https://gist.github.com/modsaid/5435473